# Rerun failed tests in VSTest task using YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to rerun failed tests in Azure Pipelines via YAML.

Project structure:

```
RerunTestsDemo.sln
  +-- ClassLibrary1.csproj
  +-- UnitTestProject1.csproj
  +-- UnitTestProject2.csproj
```

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
- automation/infra

pool: '$(AZURE_AGENT_POOL)'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/MyUnitTestProject.csproj'
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'latestStable'
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\** 
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    publishRunAttachments: true
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunType: 'basedOnTestFailurePercentage'
    rerunFailedThreshold: '30'
    rerunMaxAttempts: '2'
  env:
    # All env vars correctly configured in pipeline
```

But it is not finding any test:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following to see if it can work.

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    projects: |
      **/ClassLib1.csproj
      **/ClassLib2.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/MyUnitTestProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

**[UPDATE]**

Here is a sample as reference:

```yaml
steps:
. . .

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\** 
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    publishRunAttachments: true
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunType: 'basedOnTestFailurePercentage'
    rerunFailedThreshold: '30'
    rerunMaxAttempts: '2'
```

Comment: I am actually moving from `DotNetCoreCLI@2` because I need the `rerunMaxAttempts` mechanism.

Comment: Hi @silver, you can try using the [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) to build the whole solution. Then use the VSTest task to execute the tests.

Comment: Hi, can you post a snippet of this approach?

Comment: Hi @silver, I have updated my answer with a sample. Please check it.

Comment: Upvoting and marking as accepted answer because this did point me towards `VSBuild`. I also added my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. The test assembly task was not matching the project pattern.

This is the barebones working YAML:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*Tests*.sln'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'latestStable'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\UnitTest*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    testFiltercriteria: 'UnitTest1'
    publishRunAttachments: True
    rerunFailedTests: True
    rerunType: 'basedOnTestFailureCount'
    rerunFailedTestCasesMaxLimit: '5'
    rerunMaxAttempts: '2'
```

Output:

[image]